# When realloc shrinks a allocated block, where is the memory free'd?

Tags: c, unix, pointers, posix, realloc

I'm constructing a bigInt datatype which uses an array of unsigned short's.  In some functions, the highest order short may or may not be used, but is always allocated just in case.  To prevent endless memory consumption from basic math operations, I'd like to just realloc the array thus:

```
toReturn.numArray = realloc(toReturn.numArray, (sizeof(unsigned short)) * (toReturn.numElements - 1))
```

but I don't know if the highest order bits will be free'd (ideal) or the lowest order bits.

Comment: Do you really have ints that are megabytes in size? Otherwise shrinking will hardly be needed.

Comment: It is intended to allow RSA brute forcing (to learn it) and for complex file operations difficult to do in other ways.  But it's not megabytes, it's about 64 exabytes...

Comment: @teppic That's what I'm counting on...

Comment: @Josh - actually, forget that - I think I'm using old info.

Comment: @teppic its just a line segment.  freeing is done elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory block is relocated, data will be copied from the bottom of the old buffer, up to the new size.

If you want to preserve the top of your data, you will have to do a `malloc`/`memmove` or similar.

How this relates to your bits depends on how you map your data into the block, I would have thought.  This ought to be controllable.

Comment: Define bottom of the old buffer?  I'm not entirely sure if this is endian dependant.

Comment: How I have if, the u16 array index 0 is lowest order, and index [size] holds the most significant bits.

Comment: @Josh - 'bottom of the old buffer' = 'the memory address you were given by `malloc` and that you passed into `realloc`'

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that during downsizing the same block of memory will be returned to you with some(*downsized*) memory freed. You should not be relying on it because it is simply not guaranteed.

**C99 Standard 7.20.3.4-1: The realloc function:**

> **The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size speciﬁed by size**. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

Comment: That is not my question. I am not relying on the same memory block, I'm wondering what in the old block can be expected to exist in the new block, given that the new block is smaller.

Comment: @Josh: Does the above quotation not answer that as well? It is quite clearly and explicitly mentioned in the quote. All of them.

Comment: It is not clear.  The implied information, where bytes are lost, is not in this.  I figured in out, though.  I was being dumb.

Answer (score 1):

from 'man realloc()'

```
 The realloc() function changes the size of the block pointed
 to by ptr to size bytes and returns a pointer to the (possi-
 bly moved) block. The contents will be unchanged up  to  the
 lesser  of  the  new  and  old sizes.
```

Comment: "unchanged up to the lesser.." so the leftmost bytes are preserved. i.e. shrink("123456789\0" to 4); will be "1234" with or without trailing zero. Same for ints and shorts

Comment: depends on your interpretation. let us convert numbers to strings, you have the follwing options with srink(1): ((left aligned)"234" and "12" => "2" and "1") or ((right aligned and padded with space)"234" and "_12" => "2" and "_") or ((right aligned/filled with zeros)"234" and "012" => "2" and "0"). IT IS JUST MEMORY!

Comment: I realize it is just memory -- I care about how realloc treats it!  BY telling me it does both is useless!

Comment: leftmost is unambigous. If you "interpret" your memory "rightaligned" (myval[4] = "0123" in contrary to yourval[4] = "3","2","1","0"), in YOUR memory-modell the wrong data will be truncated

Comment: I initialize an array in C thus:

    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

    array[0] = 1;
    array[4] = 2;

Which is still accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was being a dumb-dumb.

array = realloc(array, smallerSizeNumber);

preserves array[0] to array[smallerSizeNumber - 1].

The high order bits are lost.

Comment: *"The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes."* How does this quote not answer your question?